# Type is a 'field' but it is used as a 'type'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have an issue in c# and entity framework where I use the next code:

```
public ViewModuleBase() //constructor
{
    _CurrentModel = (from Store in CurrentModelClass()
                     orderby Store.ID descending
                    select Store).FirstOrDefault();
}

Type AC_BaseClass = typeof(AC_BASE); 

virtual protected DbSet<AC_BaseClass> CurrentModelClass() //error here on AC_BaseClass
{
    return Entities.AC_BASE;
}
```

where AC_BASE is the class where I derived all my entity framework partial classes from,
the code doesn't accept the AC_BaseClass as a type and it says:
AC_BaseClass is a 'field' but it is used as a 'type'
, any idea how to solve the issue?

Comment: I think you should make ViewModuleBase generic: `ViewModuleBase<TEntity>`. But it would help to see a slightly bigger picture.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a variable or field of type `Type` as a generic type parameter. The code has to use `AC_BASE` directly:

```
virtual protected DbSet<AC_BASE> CurrentModelClass()
{
    return null;
}
```

What you were trying to do would be similar to this simplified example that does not work either:

```
Type someType = typeof(int);
someType i = 1; // <<== This will not work
```

C# does not allow this kind of "indirection", when a type in a declaration is provided through a variable. You need to use the name of the type directly.

Comment: I can't use virtual protected DbSet<AC_BASE> CurrentModelClass() because I want the AC_BASE in derived viewmodels to be dynamic where I can return DbSet<AC_BASE>, DbSet<AC_DerivedFromBase1>, DbSet<AC_DerivedFromBase2> ...

Comment: so on a derived viewmodel names viewmodelStore if I override the function and write override protected DbSet<AC_STORE> CurrentModelClass() , it says return type must be AC_BASE to match overridden member

Comment: @ZORRO_BLANCO The "signature" (i.e. the return type + all the parameter types) of a method in a derived class must match the signature of the method that you are overriding. Moreover, once you declare the method returning `DbSet<AC_BASE>`, you wouldn't be able to return `DbSet<AC_STORE>` from it, because the two generic instances are not covariant, even though `AC_STORE` derives from `AC_BASE`.

Comment: Yes, I know that, what I have to do to make it accept all types?

Comment: @ZORRO_BLANCO You need to declare the method returning `DbSet<AC_BASE>`, and construct a `DbSet<AC_BASE>` from `DbSet<AC_STORE>` inside the method, for example, by copying records. This is probably going to be rather inefficient. Provide a different method, say, `CurrentModelClassSpecific` or something like that, for users who need `DbSet<AC_STORE>`.